# I want to use subquery with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

first of all, my english is not very good. I'm sorry for that. 
When I run this sql code, my data multiple count , I think it is for group by

```
select * from (
```

My firs select

```
SELECT ct.name as ILAD, FsktkKpst.Ad as nitelik1,Count(ky.name) AS KAdet, SUM(kme.nufus) AS KNufus
                        FROM
                        (select 1 as ID, '0-250 Kisilik' AD from dual
                            union all
                            select 2 as ID, '251-500 Kisilik' AD from dual
                            union all
                            select 3 as ID, '501-1000 Kisilik' AD from dual
                            union all
                            select 4 as ID, '1000-1500 Kisilik' AD from dual
                            union all
                            select 5 as ID, '>1501 Kisilik' AD from dual) FsktkKpst,
                            foseptik_evw f, village ky,city ct,county cy,koymahalleenvanteri kme  
                        WHERE  ky.id = kme.koyid(+) 
                               AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   foseptik_evw fs 
                                           WHERE  f.koyid = ky.id and f.KOYBAGLISIID is null   AND f.kapasite >=0 and f.AKTF!=-1 and f.AKTF !=0 ) 
                               AND ky.countyid = cy.id 
                               AND cy.cityid = ct.id
                               and ct.id = f.ILID 
                               AND f.ILID ='{6B7-C6EC-40F-8CC25991}' and f.KAPASITE=fsktkKpst.Id group by f.KAPASITE, fsktkKpst.Ad ,ct.name order by f.KAPASITE ),
```

second select

```
( SELECT ct.name as ILAD,FsktkKpst.Ad, SUM(kme.nufus) AS KBNufus,Count(kb.name) AS KBAdet 
    FROM 
     (select 1 as ID, '0-250 Kisilik' AD from dual
                        union all
                        select 2 as ID, '251-500 Kisilik' AD from dual
                        union all
                        select 3 as ID, '501-1000 Kisilik' AD from dual
                        union all
                        select 4 as ID, '1000-1500 Kisilik' AD from dual
                        union all
                        select 5 as ID, '>1501 Kisilik' AD from dual) FsktkKpst,

      foseptik_evw f, villagebound kb,village ky,city ct,county cy,koymahalleenvanteri kme 
    WHERE  kb.id = kme.koybaglisiid(+) 
           AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   asu_foseptik_evw fs 
                       WHERE  f.KOYBAGLISIID = kb.id  AND f.kapasite >= 0 and f.AKTF!=-1 and f.AKTF !=0 ) 
           AND kb.villageid = ky.id               
           AND ky.countyid = cy.id
           AND cy.cityid = ct.id
           and ct.id = f.ILID
           AND ct.id = '{6B7-C6EC-40F-8CC25991}'  and f.KAPASITE=fsktkKpst.Id group by f.KAPASITE , fsktkKpst.Ad, ct.name order by f.KAPASITE )
```

my data is multiplying as much as the number of records in each query.my data is running smoothly. when I run queries separately

Comment: Resul, try using `ANSI-92` SQL format where tables are without comma seperated, including (`inner`/`left`/`right`/`outer`) `join` keywords. This way, they become easier to read and understand.

Comment: If it helps - your English is just fine.