# How can I add Table2 columns to table1

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 sql query.

first select:

```
string sql1 ="@select ( ...... )"
DbCommand command1 = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql1);
DataTable dt1 = base.Select(command1);
```

second select:

```
 string sql2 ="@select ( ...... )"
 DbCommand command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql2);
 DataTable dt2 = base.Select(command);
```

I want to first result set dt1 then second result set dt2. Finally I want add columns dt2 to dt1. from C#

Comment: Columns are important. Add some sample data to the question and describe the expected output. You may also be able to do it using a single query, depending to the requirement. At least at the moment it's not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to say. Can I dt1.Columns.Add(dt2.columns) ? by the way my english not good. sorry for that

Comment: It's easier to share a simple sample data and the expected output. I doubt that `dt1.Columns.Add(dt2.columns)` be even close to what you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958715/i-want-to-use-subquery-with-group-by

Comment: Usually users are not interested to such long queries while you can share a better example. Such query is not what expected from a [MCVE]. Simplify your question to two tables like `Product(Id, Name, CategoryId, Price)`, `Category(Id, Name)` and share 2-3 records of data and also shape of the expected output.

Comment: May be after more than one and half year being member in stackoverflow, it's a good time to read [ASK] and [MCVE]. This way, you can enhance the quality of your question a lot and increase chance of receiving some good answers. The other thing at which you need to take a look is [Tour], as I see you have never accepted a question.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. i will do what you say

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, when I said it's unclear what you are asking, it's not about your English language skill, it's about the points that I described about example. Don't worry too much about English language skill. Writing in a way that other people understand is not too hard and you are doing so.

Comment: I am understand you , you are right . Firstly I will read documents then I will try more good question

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins here to join the data of two or more tables:

Please refer the example given in the below link:
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join)

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that assuming that you have the same columns in the 2 queries is to use union all

```
string sql = "@select ( ...... ) union all @select ( ...... )"
```

Comment: I do this but I want to print the query results side by side

Comment: At least based on the [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959885/how-can-%c4%b1-add-table2-columns-to-table1#comment96681229_54959885) it seems the OP is looking for a join. Which cannot be answered without having an example of input and output columns.